# How to send particular DIV as a PDF on email Onclick button in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, pdf, sendmail

> I am working on project in angular. Im new in angular. want to send
>   particular DIV as a PDF to email onclick button? Is it possible in
>   angular?

Answer (score 0):

The PDF should be rather generated by your server-side script then downloaded or output via Angular interface. You may also try using solutions like https://parall.ax/products/jspdf
but I am not sure if that would be efficient for lager PDF documents.

Comment: im using jspdf for creating pdf of div and it works for me. but i dont have any idea for sendmail

Comment: No, this is not possible. You can't send emails with HTML/JS only. The only think you could do is opening user mail client with  `maito` e.g. `<button href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">Send Mail</button>`